# Browser performance. Which way is better: $('#item1 img[src]').qtip( {..}); -vs- $('#item1').qtip( {..});?

Tags: selector, qtip

Which way is better: `$('#item1 img[src]').qtip( {..});`  -OR-  `$('#item1').qtip( {..});`  ?
It works both ways. Would you recommend to use `img[src]` as a part of the selector?  Is it normal?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are two separate things:

```
$('#item1 img[src]').qtip( {..});
```

Selects an image element within an element with id `item1`.

```
$('#item1').qtip( {..});
```

Selects an element with id `item1`.

**Also**

What does `img[src]` do?

I only know that format when adding a src to it. Otherwise it does just nothing if it works.

```
$('img[src*="you_src_you_want_to_select"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) in jQuery 1.3.x+, selects are performed from outer to inner (bottom to top, or right to left).  jQuery is optimized for finding by ID, so by descending from an ID and adding more specific matching rules on the right without being overly specific, it is fair to say that you may see performance improvements.

I recommend checking out this presentation by Paul Irish for more details on selector performance:

http://paulirish.com/2009/perf/